# How to update variable in fetch

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, fetch

```
const test = () => {
let shown = { total: 0, thisWeek: 0, thisWeekData: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }

modalIds.map(async (data) => {
  await fetch("api/statistics/private/get?modalId=" + data.modalId)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.success) {
        shown = DataForAllShown(shown, data, "views")


      }
    })
})
return shown
}
```

The value of shown is always the same as the initial value, but the function DataForAllShown() gives it a new value. When trying to later access the variable it remains the same.

I understand that fetch is always async, but how can I update a variable outside of fetch and access it right after fetching?

Comment: You have another issue also...overwriting the same variable if more than one request passes the `data.success` condition. What is supposed to happen if more than one is true?

Comment: This essentially defeats the purpose of a code being asynchronous. You should fetch the data and perform something with that data. Ideally, what you do with your variable `shown`, should be performed inside fetch.

Comment: @charlietfl I am overwriting the same variable because I need to add up the data from multiple fetches. The function DataForAllShown takes in the shown parameter and updates the parameters in it.

Comment: What does "add up the data" mean in more detail? Reassigning the value of `shown` overwrites any previous value as if it never existed

Comment: @EhsanMahmud I need to add up the data and then return it, I can not do anything with the variable in the fetch because I need the full version of it after fetch is done.

Comment: @charlietfl for example, on the first iteration of mapping the value of shown.total is updated to 2, on the second iteration of mapping it would be updated to 4, etc...

Comment: Providing a sample of expected results will help all from guessing. That explanation is still too vague. In other words an [mcve]

Comment: What you will need is map the array of fetch promises and use map() properly to store the returned array ...then return resolved Promise.all promise from test()

Comment: After first iteration of mapping the expected result of shown is:{ total: 2, thisWeek: 2, thisWeekData: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0] }. After second iteration of mapping the expected result of shown is:{ total: 4, thisWeek: 4, thisWeekData: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2] }. I need the final value.

Comment: If `DataForAllShown()` returns the updated object then you need to make `test()` async so it runs through all iterations and returns a promise with final result.

Comment: Using a `for` loop instead of map() would accomplish that also

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your help, will work on fixing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have noticed is, You have return shown outside of promise. Also using **Promise.all()** will make more sense for map objects.

Try modifying code something like below:

```js
const test = async () => {
    let shown = { total: 0, thisWeek: 0, thisWeekData: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }

    await Promise.all(modalIds.map(async (data) => {
        let response = await fetch("api/statistics/private/get?modalId=" + data.modalId);
        let jsonData = await response.json();
        if (jsonData.success) {
            shown= DataForAllShown(shown, jsonData, "views");
        }
    }));
    
    return shown;

}
```

Comment: So what gets returned to `test()` call? This does not solve OP's issue, just part of it. Also uses `map()` incorrectly

Comment: Have made the test() function as async so it will block the code and will return from this line: return DataForAllShown(shown, data, "views");

Comment: That returns to `map()`, not the outer function. This is not doing what you think it is doing

Comment: Ohh! sorry I didn't notice map ;) Let me delete this

Comment: Just modified the answer again

Comment: Right and OP needs to realize that what is now returned is a promise and not the simple object. Also `swan` is a typo

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, data is also declared twice, but overall it works.